# WEB API 2 Identity - work with exisiting database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to use web api 2 with token based authentication. But I want to use my own database. Users are already created. I have renamed the tables in OnModelCreating,
 so I have proper tables names like Users, UserRole instead of Asp.netUsers etc. I change connection string for ApplicationDbContext for connect to my database.

So when I register the new user via web api, it creates the user properly in the tables, and it ok. But when i try to create a new bearer Token and when it try's to look up for the user as below, it always returns null. 
Not sure why. All my configs are default so I can not understand it. When I try to  search for user I always get null for below.
var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

Do I have to do anything special to make web api 2 authentication work wiht my exisiting database?

Comment: You can try to trace SQL query that is executing during authentication. Maybe it will give some details. As for me issue can be in password hashing mechanism, but it's just a guess

Comment: I check profiler for one user - I see several queries, one of them (183 rows   of text :-) )  return users data. After that, I do not move in this direction.  May be later I do it, if situation will be not clear

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I have not all clear, but now it work correct. Why there was a problem: when I change ApplicationDbContext constructor for my connection string, first time I cannot to do right, 
because was error in start (Unknow distributor Ado.net providerName), so I read in parameters ApplicationDbContext real connection string ("Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Initial Catalog=NameDB; ......... ).

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Initial Catalog=NameDB; .........")
        {
        }
```

Compiling was ok, but I have problem above. 
After that I read right text for constructor (parameter - name connection string from Web.config -"MyConnection"),

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("MyConnection")
        {
        }
```

and delete tag providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" for this connection string. Was error "Need providerName...", and I return this tag. After that start was ok, and application work correct, how can I see.